# constructing two dimensional array dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some values in JavaScript array as shown

```
var sampledata = {10,20,30,40};// these values would come from database later
```

I want to create a two dimensional array with these values.

I want to create a array as

```
var newData = [[0,10],[1,20],[2,30],[3,40]]
```

Comment: The sample data syntax is invalid. Also, i don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Do you mean `var sampledata = [10,20,30,40];`

Answer (score 4):

Pure JavaScript:

```
var newData = [];
var sampledata = [10,20,30,40];
for (var i = 0; i < sampledata.length; i++) {
    newData.push([i, sampledata[i]]);
}
```

Using higher-order functions:

```
var newData = sampledata.map(function(el, i) {
    return [i, el];
})
```

Comment: your JQuery example needs to return `[[i, el]]` or it will add two items instead of a nested array of two items.

Comment: @Yanick - I don't have a jQuery example. If you're talking about the example that uses `map` then, no, it should not return `[[i, el]]`. The function given to `map` should return elements of `newData`, which are one-dimensional arrays.

Comment: my mistake. I don't know why, but when I tried the first time on jsfiddle.net, I got `[0,10,1,20,2,30,...]`. I cannot reproduce this, so I assume it must have been my fault, or something else...

Answer (score 3):

if sampledata is an array

```
var sampledata = [10,20,30,40]
var newData  = []
jQuery.each(sampledata,function(i,data){newData.push([i,data])})
```

Comment: Thank you Naren Sisodiya , i have tried for(var i=0li<sampledata.length;i++) {newData.push([i,data]) its not working , are they both same ??

Comment: @Kiran - Use `sampledata[i]` where you currently have `data`. See my answer for a full example.

Comment: look at lwburk's response for plain javascript, I've used jQuery